# Build on or upon

Tags: expressions

Which one is correct / works better for a formal writing?

... framework is limited by the assumptions it was built on

or

... framework is limited by the assumptions it was built upon

A quick Google search showed both are used, but "built on" is used more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Upon" is more formal than "on".

According to Oxford English Dictionary
(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upon):

***Upon***

more formal term for ***on***, especially in abstract senses

‘a school's dependence upon parental support’